# How to register an Error in Datadog's "APM Error Tracking" dashboard using Java Rest API?

Tags: datadog

I have to send an abnormal event or incident as a Java Stacktrace to Datadog backend using Datadog's Java Rest API. I am able to send Events and Metrics but they show up in their respective dashboards but not in "APM Error Tracking" dashboard.

I need to do this using Java Rest API only because this Error is posted from my backend which is not host of customer application or datadog agent.

Is there a way I can post an Error to "APM's Error Tracking" dashboard using Java Rest API?

**UPDATE**

My use case is different. I am not a Datadog customer. I am developer of a monitoring solution that complements Datadog. Like Datadog, I also have a client-side Java agent (which sits along with Datadog's Java agent) and a backend engine. My client-side agent collects certain data which is sent to my backend engine for analysis. If my backend detects a defect, I need to register that as an Error in Datadog's "APM Error Tracking" dashboard on my customer's Datadog account.

Answer (score 3):

Datadog APM provides distributed tracing. Therefore the "APM Error Tracking" data is populated from traces and spans that arrive from your application rather than events or metrics.
If you haven't already researched [Datadog Auto Instrumentation](https://www.datadoghq.com/auto-instrumentation/) then I would advise doing so, as its aim is to handle all of your tracing automatically and is the easiest way to start populating trace data from your applications.

If auto instrumentation is not possible Datadog has many libraries + packages for explicitly creating traces and spans manually in code. To mark a span as an error you should set the Error and Exception fields. I am using Datadog in C# rather than Java so there may be some small differences but I would imagine the core ideas should be similar across all of their supported stacks.

```
ISpan span = Tracer.Instance.StartActive("my_operation").Span;
span.SetException(ex);
span.Error = true
```

> I need to do this using Java Rest API only because this Error is
> posted from my backend which is not host of customer application or
> datadog agent.

Also in case you are not already aware, you do not need each application/backend to host a Datadog agent. I believe it is recommended to host a central agent that will receive traces/events/logs etc from your applications and forward them to Datadog. Your applications need network access to that central agent and it will handle aspects like api keys, sampling etc. As for sending traces directly to an API and bypassing the agent all together, I have not seen that setup before. I know they have a public endpoint for logs but you may have to work around sending traces with some kind of agent (either central or installed on your applications host). Your customer support rep or datadog support are probably best to confirm that particular aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a trace and spans via an API request](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/send_traces_to_agent_by_api/), but a trace has more data than just an error; it includes metadata about where the error originated and execution timing. Additionally, this is a client-side API provided by the Agent, so you make requests to the locally running Datadog agent rather than to the web. There is no web API for this functionality.

As IanSoc mentioned, instrumenting your codebase is the normal way to populate the APM dashboard. Once you have instrumented your code for tracing, you can [connect your logs with your traces](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/other_telemetry/connect_logs_and_traces/).